# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method - Firebase issue despite not using FirebaseMessagingService?

Tags: java, android

So I'm using Firebase to get my app analytics but my users have been reporting crashes which I couldn't re-create (the crash) in any of my test devices.

I wrote a bug reporting library within my app which would send me the verbose logs via email and found out the main cause.

Surprisingly, I am not even using FirebaseMessagingService in my app so would like to know if someone can help me out here? Tried searching for the solution but couldn't find it so creating a thread here.

Here's the log:

```
ava.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method zzad()Lcom/google/firebase/iid/zzan; in class Lcom/google/firebase/iid/zzan; or its super classes (declaration of 'com.google.firebase.iid.zzan' appears in /data/app/com.myapp.myapp-1/base.apk:classes2.dex)
at com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService.zzb(Unknown Source)
at com.google.firebase.iid.zzb.onStartCommand(Unknown Source)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:3770)
at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap23(ActivityThread.java)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1764)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6816)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1563)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1451)
```

My build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
//apply plugin: 'com.google.android.gms.oss-licenses-plugin'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.myapp.myapp"
        minSdkVersion 18
        targetSdkVersion 28
        multiDexEnabled true
        resConfigs "en"
        compileOptions {
            sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
            targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/dependencies.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LGPL2.1'
        exclude 'META-INF/services/com.fasterxml.jackson.core.ObjectCodec'
        exclude 'META-INF/services/com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonFactory'
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
    dexOptions {
        jumboMode true
    }
}

repositories {
    google()
    flatDir {
        dirs 'libs'
    }
    maven {
        url "https://jitpack.io"
    }
    jcenter()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'com.devbrackets.android:exomedia:4.0.3'

    // Radio
    implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer:r2.4.3'
    implementation 'com.cleveroad:audiovisualization:1.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.5'

    // General
    implementation 'org.jsoup:jsoup:1.11.2'
    implementation 'com.onesignal:OneSignal:3.10.6'
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
    implementation 'com.duolingo.open:rtl-viewpager:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.github.chrisbanes:PhotoView:1.3.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'

    // Google Support Libraries
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex-instrumentation:1.0.3'
    implementation "com.android.support:exifinterface:$supportlib_version"
    implementation "com.android.support:cardview-v7:$supportlib_version"
    implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:$supportlib_version"
    implementation "com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:$supportlib_version"
    implementation "com.android.support:design:$supportlib_version"
    implementation "com.android.support:support-v4:$supportlib_version"
    implementation "com.android.support:support-core-utils:$supportlib_version"
    implementation "com.android.support:support-media-compat:$supportlib_version"
    implementation "com.android.support:customtabs:$supportlib_version"
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'

    // Google Services
    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-oss-licenses:$gps_version"
    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:$gps_version"
    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:$gps_version"
    implementation files('libs/YouTubeAndroidPlayerApi.jar')

    // Firebase
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.3'

    // Flurry Analytics
    implementation 'com.flurry.android:analytics:11.6.0@aar'

    // About Fragment
    implementation project(':library')
    implementation project(':crashlib')

    // Easyrest Library
    implementation('com.github.fcopardo:easyrest:v1.4.2@aar') {
        transitive = true
    }

    // ta4j for technical analysis
    implementation 'org.ta4j:ta4j-core:0.11'

    // display libraries
    implementation 'com.github.florent37:fiftyshadesof:1.0.0'

    // retrofit for quick and safe network communication
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.5.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.5.0'
    implementation 'com.github.faruktoptas:RetrofitRssConverterFactory:0.0.2'

    // RxJava for multithreaded network requests with retrofit
    implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.1.1'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava2:2.5.0'

    // PriceChart Library
    implementation 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v3.0.3'

    // Okhttp And Logging
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.14.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.12.1'

    // Custom font lib
    implementation 'uk.co.chrisjenx:calligraphy:2.3.0'

    // Material Dialogs - Sort By Menu
    implementation 'com.afollestad.material-dialogs:core:0.9.6.0'

    // Toggle Button - Currency Card
    implementation 'com.nex3z:toggle-button-group:1.1.2'

    // Favrorite Button - Star
    implementation 'com.github.ivbaranov:materialfavoritebutton:0.1.5'

    // Bottom Dialog Sheet
    implementation 'com.github.marcoscgdev:DialogSheet:1.0.5'

    // Intro Lib
    implementation 'agency.tango.android:material-intro-screen:0.0.5'

    implementation 'com.jakewharton.threetenabp:threetenabp:1.2.0'

}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
// Work around
com.google.gms.googleservices.GoogleServicesPlugin.config.disableVersionCheck = true
```

Project gradle:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
        maven {
            url 'https://jitpack.io'
        }
    }
}

buildscript {
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.2'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'
        classpath 'com.jfrog.bintray.gradle:gradle-bintray-plugin:1.7.3'
        classpath 'com.github.dcendents:android-maven-gradle-plugin:2.0'
        //classpath 'com.google.android.gms:oss-licenses-plugin:0.9.4'
    }
    repositories {
        google()
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com/'
        }
        jcenter()
    }
}

ext {
    supportlib_version = '28.0.0'
    gps_version = '[16.0.0, 17.0.0)'
    fb_version = '[15.0.0, 17.0.0)'
    archRoomVersion = "1.0.0"
}

//Ensure that all dependencies use the same version of the Android Support library
subprojects {
    project.configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { details ->
            if (details.requested.group == 'com.android.support'
                    && !details.requested.name.contains('multidex')) {
                details.useVersion "$supportlib_version"
            }
            if (details.requested.group == 'com.google.android.gms'
                    && !details.requested.name.contains('multidex')) {
                details.useVersion "$gps_version"
            }
            if (details.requested.group == 'com.google.firebase'
                    && !details.requested.name.contains('multidex')) {
                details.useVersion "$fb_version"
            }
        }
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

This is likely to be caused by a conflict of different versions of library dependencies between the compiled and runtime version of your library/app. It could be that one of your other dependencies depends on an older version of FCM or other libraries. Basically, your project is probably depending on different versions of a same library.

As Martin mentioned in his answer, remove the version check and the exact conflict should be shown in the log if you compile again, then you can resolve it very easily.

Answer (score 1):

remove this line (it causes more problems than it would solve - it only hides the problems):

```
com.google.gms.googleservices.GoogleServicesPlugin.config.disableVersionCheck = true
```

---

the dependencies should look alike this (`ads` and `gcm` are now below  `com.google.firebase`):

```
// Google Services
implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:16.1.0"
implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:16.0.1"
// implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:17.2.0"

// Firebase
implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.8"
implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.5.0"
implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:17.2.0"
```

of course, this would also require name-space changes in code, as well as migrating from `GCM` to `FCM`, but this migration would definitely be sooner or later be due, to to `GCM` being shut down.

Comment: Removing that line throws build error:

ERROR: In project 'app' a resolved Google Play services library dependency depends on another at an exact version (e.g. "[15.1.
0]", but isn't being resolved to that version. Behavior exhibited by the library will be unknown.

Comment: Dependency failing: com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:15.0.2 -> com.google.firebase:firebase-iid@[15.1.0], but fire
base-iid version was 16.2.0.

Comment: -- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.firebase:firebase-core@16.0.3
-- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics@16.4.0
-- Project 'app' depends onto com.onesignal:OneSignal@3.10.6
-- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging@15.0.2
-- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-api@16.4.0
-- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.firebase:firebase-core@16.0.8
-- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.firebase:firebase-iid@16.2.0

Comment: @StevenRõgrê your `build.gradle` does not reflect any of that, nor does it match the error message.... `com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:16.1.0` (others are still at `16.0.0`) would be the current version. please update the question with all dependencies, so that I could copy & paste that.

Comment: I've updated the OP with my full build.gradle and project gradle. Please check.